# Accessing aliased fields in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

In a query I create lots of fields using the `CASE` expression.

I need to reference these fields later on in the query but it seems I can't access the field using its alias - I have to repeat the `CASE` expression every time I want to reference its value.

Is there a simple way to access these fields?

Comment: Can you give us some piece of code? Perhaps using functions will resolve your problem, but I'll be easier if you give us some example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CTEs (assuming SQL Server 2005+), like this very basic example:

```
DECLARE @Val INT
SET @Val = 1

;WITH CTEExample AS
(
SELECT CASE @Val WHEN 1 THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END AS MyCaseField1
)

SELECT * FROM CTEExample WHERE MyCaseField1 = 'A'
```

Comment: +1 excellent example of a good use of CTE's to make your life easier!

Answer (score 0):

why not simply make a subquery

eg

```
SELECT  foo.column
FROM    (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN yourcase THEN 'a'
        ELSE 'b'
        END AS 'column'
    FROM    yourtable) AS foo
```

but this can be done with CTEs either ([look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932354/accessing-query-fields-in-t-sql/4932379#4932379))

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `CROSS APPLY` for this [as in this tip by Itzik Ben Gan](http://www.sqlmag.com/blogs/puzzled-by-t-sql/tabid/1023/entryid/72321/Tip-APPLY-and-Reuse-of-Column-Aliases.aspx).

```
SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate, Week_Day
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
  CROSS APPLY 
 (SELECT DATEPART(weekday, DATEADD(day, @@DATEFIRST - 7, OrderDate)) AS Week_Day) AS A
WHERE Week_Day NOT IN (1, 7);
```

You should be aware that reusing aliases in a `where` clause will render the predicate unsargable however so should be used with caution (this applies regardless of whether you use `APPLY` or a CTE)